# Extract the Coefficients of a Linear Equation

Tags: code-golf, string, number, parsing

Given a linear equation `mx+n`, return `n` and `m`. However, the equation may be in any of the following formats:

```
5x+2 -> 5 2
5x-2 -> 5 -2
5x   -> 5 0
-2   -> 0 -2
x    -> 1 0
```

Here are the formats, where each `?` stands for a positive integer written without leading zeroes

```
?x+?
?x-?
-?x+?
-?x-?
x+?
x-?
?
-?
?x
-?x
x
```

All of these cases must be handled.

### Specifications:

- You can assume that the equation is in one of the above formats, i.e. it matches the regex `^(-?[123456789]\d*)?x([+-][123456789]\d*)?|-?[123456789]\d*$`.

### Test Cases:

```
-2x+3 -> -2 3
44x   -> 44 0
-123  -> 0 -123
x     -> 1 0
-1x   -> -1 0
```

Comment: What about output formats? Would e.g. `1 +2` be a valid output for `1x+2`?

Comment: Adding on to what @PeterTaylor said, the python answer adds an `L` to the end of numbers if they get too big. Should this be allowed?

Comment: @PeterTaylor You can use any valid output format.

Comment: Is it valid to output constants as length-1 lists, and true linear polynomials as length-2 lists? So for example, `7x` is output as `7 0` but `7` is output as just `7`?

Comment: @GregMartin No, you must always output both numbers.

Comment: @Challenger5 are leading spaces allowed (for negative numbers), i.e. `-2x` -> `<space>-2 0`

Comment: (1) The list of cases is missing `x+?` and `x-?`. (2) Is it on purpose that the regex (as well as the list) is excluding `-x`, `-x+?` and `-x-?` ? (3) Those are expressions, not equations. :P

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen (1) Fixed. (2) No, but I'm afraid I'll break existing answers. (3) `y=`

Comment: 327*x is a valid input? 3*y is a valid input? If both 23*x and 23x are valid input it seems to me not a <number> question but one regex one...

Comment: @RosLuP The `*`s in the regex are metacharacters, it is not allowed in the input.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
j=1j
c=eval(input().replace(*'xj'))
print c.imag,c.real
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JYnLDoMgFAV/hd2F@ki0upHwJ25uKW0giAQf4e8RcXNmJue3BrIR7WCMVQ91RvMgz20EHovVO3MYSnX9HUUjTNr5YxcWl88Xp43PyYjOcCnUiZaWk7I2KG9RKvqCaIAx7oN2O5GtXvBfy3yjTekC)

Uses Python's built-in code evaluation. The input is formatted like a complex number by replacing `x` with`j`, Python's complex unit. Because only literals like `2j` are recognized, but not `j` or `-j`, the variable `j` is assigned as `1j` to cover those.

Unfortunately, Python doesn't seem to have a built-in to convert a complex number to a pair of reals.

Comment: Oh nice thinking :D

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 16 bytes

Inspired by [xnor's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120288/66104):

```
ReIm[I#/.x->-I]&
```

Takes input as a literal expression (not a string), and returns a pair of numbers. It works by making `x` a complex number then taking the real and imaginary parts — the only non-obvious bit is multiplying by *i* to start with, to get the output in the right order.

We can also use

```
ReIm[x=-I;I#]&
```

for 14 bytes (tied with Jelly!), but setting `x` to equal *-i* before taking the input, instead of just replacing `x` afterwards, feels like cheating…

Comment: Nice solution. I never new it had a `ReIm` function, I've always been doing `{Re[#],Im[#]}&`. You've helped a lot there.

Comment: @IanMiller, `ReIm` was only introduced in version 10.1, so it's possible your copy of Mathematica doesn't have it.

Comment: Ah. I do have 10.1 but I have been using old versions for far longer. They add way too many functions each update. :).

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> 48 bytes

```js
s=>([a,b]=s.split(/x\+?/),1/b?[a||1,b||0]:[0,s])
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>([a,b]=s.split(/x\+?/),1/b?[a||1,b||0]:[0,s])

console.log(f("-2x+3")) // -> -2 3
console.log(f("44x"))   // -> 44 0
console.log(f("-123"))  // -> 0 -123
console.log(f("x"))     // -> 1 0
console.log(f("-1x"))   // -> -1 0
```

Comment: works not for `-x` try my regex

Comment: @JörgHülsermann If I understand the rules correctly, `-x` is not a valid input.

Comment: You are right sorry

Answer (score 3):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
s:+::
s:x: :
t
s:^:0 :
:
s:^ :1 :
s: $: 0:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#Fci7DQAxCATRnCoInKGTjD/JFuMm7GC75yAZPU1cGCAXhEJe4qCnah2Fa0EbtCNi04ZsfhXJVmhT1kr5mDWcPw)

I/O: one per line.

-2 bytes thanks to @KritixiLithos.

Comment: You can do `t` and `:` instead of using the `a` label

Comment: @KritixiLithos Seems to work somehow, thanks!

Comment: The first two substitutions can be combined into one.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”x;ṣ”xVṫ-µ¬ṂW+
```

Test suite at **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#FYs7DsJADET7OUX6yJKz2XwQEhegB3EFTuAySsMloEKiISVbrKAy4iC7F1mcYvw80puSp5tsU7yvPKT4JA26pDgf65LeLw2/z/eS50XD3i7rQ4PxbMnTtaJdZbtTKY3UDk6oBbVSe5AX6tCDBowC2ggEDZvEcGwam2fVG731jtHbOzBGXnWWPw)**

#### How?

```
”x;ṣ”xVṫ-µ¬ṂW+ - Main link: list of characters s  examples: "5x-2"         "x"       "-123"
”x             - literal 'x'
  ;            - concatenate with s                        "x5x-2"        "xx"      "x-123"
   ṣ”x         - split on 'x's                        ["","5","-2]  ["","",""]  ["","-123"]
      V        - evaluate as Jelly code (vectorises)      [0,5,-2]     [0,0,0]     [0,-123]
       ṫ-      - tail from index -1 inclusive               [5,-2]       [0,0]     [0,-123]
         µ     - monadic chain separation (call that z)
          ¬    - not z                                       [0,0]       [1,1]        [1,0]
           Ṃ   - minimum                                         0           1            0
            W  - wrap in a list                                [0]         [1]          [0]
             + - add to z (vectorises)                      [5,-2]       [1,0]     [0,-123]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
Coefficient[#,x,{1,0}]&
```

[Try it online](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/)

copy and paste with ctrl-v this code

```
Coefficient[#,x,{1,0}]&[-2x+3]
```

and press shift+enter to run

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 73 Bytes

```php
preg_match("#((.*)x)?\+?(.*)#",$argn,$t);echo$t[1]?$t[2]?:1:0," ",+$t[3];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#LY2xDoIwFEV3vsI8GKi0RmADkw6GwUUXN2hIQyo4SMmzQxOjv44Uupx7b85L3olPwxQoRI0tqkmjeY59/Kva6@1@OVekDB4aleyGuAYLFFjqmK11Ze6ag03yza@Z@enTMi/ZJpmXSwr5jiT2I/nME6q@fUmzfIMwjg97YglvEu5aCHQ9o5EhpeoGHZk6FXxhJniRFkcKO6DJsnNRzu4AmhHK4Dv/AQ)

## PHP, 91 Bytes

works also with `-x`

```
preg_match("#((-)?(\d+)?x)?\+?(-?\d+)?#",$argn,$t);echo$t[2],$t[1]?$t[3]?:1:0," ",$t[4]?:0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#LY0/D4IwEMV3PoU5GNpAE/44gUkHw@CiixsQQrSCg7Q5OzQx@tWxLSzvvd@9u9yBq0kFAlFij0JJ1M95JL@6P1@up2NNq@AhUQy3iTRgIAHmJPfJa@GSExP7uFq@0eaGrR1bO7Z11rvhHQ04zvSzKBRj/xq0fQUhIYxy0t5jyg3lbcwJ455CSPxBEmlaidskI93knaUm67jVouNlVqYJ7MAN9xbTanGL0M5QBd/lDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 71 bytes

```python
lambda s:([0,]+[int(x or`1-i`)for i,x in enumerate(s.split('x'))])[-2:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VY/LCsMgEEX3/YrZqWQsiTGbQL7ECklpAkJeGAP@vVVDCt0Mc@bcu5ipe4V5WN6fAY6WqhJ1oczqqIfN9hU3PZs2CwY9mBXG9VxGO7iRHs9jn42jxBPGNFNctDqkpEObkkqRxheCoGpQaI0J@YX85kxlhqzKWyVT/Ywv6shcYJ0PUiYt5e0rUV/duPy3dfuA3cZnYKKOYRpdZ8MX)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
#~CoefficientList~x/.{a_}:>{a,0}&
```

Pure function taking an expression in the expected format (note: not a string, but a pure expression like `-2x+3`), and returning an ordered pair of integers with the constant coefficient appearing first (for example, `-2x+3` returns `{3,-2}`).

The builtin `CoefficientList` (which works for polynomials of any degree) does the heavy lifting; its default behavior is to return constants as length-1 lists, so `/.{a_}:>{a,0}` overrides that and makes the `0` coefficient of `x` appear explicitly.

Comment: I was wondering how long it would be until a Mathematica answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 38 bytes

```
x$
x+0
^[^+-]*$
0x+$+
^[^-\d]
1$+
-
+-
```

Definitely can be improved.

Possibly stretching how we are allowed to format output. It just outputs a complete equation, as in `n` and `m` separated by `x+`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@1@hwlWhbcAVFx2nrRurpcJlUKGtog3i6sakxHIZAtm6XNq6//9X6BoCAA)

Comment: This fails for an input like `x-1`

Comment: @Leo Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I'm fairly confident you can replace `[^+-]*` with `\w*`

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 45 bytes

```matlab
@(a)[imag(u=eval(strrep(a,'x','j'))),real(u)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#TcvBCoMwDMbx@54il5EEm6K1V8X3EA891LGxwahz9O1rSx3smF/@3zpordNEjuf7y91oH/zXPWn7hODf5BRGVPhAZlbB58fOS1oJxcSmR4YryAhioL9ktDZmgorWQltQOlPCii2Us3AtT@5@6d9eMqYD)

Evaluate the expression, with `x` replaced by complex `j`. Octave is very flexible when it comes to complex expressions, with `j`,`1j`,`i` and `1i` all equivalent (with the advantage that `1j` and `1i` cannot be overwritten by variables, but that's irrelevant for this challenge). Inline expression is used to build a list of `[imag(u) real(u)]` with `u` the complex number.

I initially wanted to try a more idiomatic approach, using the built-in `sym2poly`. For example (already at 47 bytes to make sure `0*x` is handled):

```matlab
@(a)sym2poly([strrep(a,'x','*x') '+x^2']))(2:3)
```

This one however failed on the case of `x` without coefficient. In the end a real/complex setup like `xnor` turned out to be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
120'i'ZtU&Zj
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29oZKCeqR5VEqoWlfX/v3qFtqU6AA)

Port of my Octave answer, but of course adapted for compactness in MATL. Explanation:

```
120'i'Zt     % Replace character 120 ('x') by 'i' in input (implicit).
             % (Used 120 instead of 'x' to save a separator between 'x' and 'i')
        U    % Convert string to complex number
         &Zj % Split complex number in real and imaginary part. Implicit display.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),<s>145</s> <s>138</s> 112 bytes

```c
f(char*s){int a,b,i=0;sscanf(s,"%dx%d",&a,&b);if(L!=0)i=(int)(L-s);printf("%d %d",s[i]=='x'?a:0,s[i]=='x'?b:a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#TY7BDoIwEETvfMUKQbpaDcGEA7X6A/yB8VAolU20mhYSEuO3a/Gic9uX2ZlJyLbXUXd7P2i6b/tDlPyII3v5It0Zsh3UEFjbO@Z5NmUIEdkBbooswycYFu@KoGldFkUZowAA1w2js5CL19uwtldu5fE5PynecJK58L5V1oS8ONVTqmO@VHzZoCDD6oXMkSQLdmT1xqN4hD1DqEk1zFZ/orOUYchRVfnf1VQKQ@H7Aw)

```c
void f(char*s)
{
    int a,b,i=0;
    sscanf(s,"%dx%d",&a,&b);

    if(L!=0)
      i=(int)(L-s);

    printf("%d %d",s[i]=='x'?a:0,s[i]=='x'?b:a);
}
```

Can definitely be shortened, but dont see it now!

Comment: 1. You don't need the space in `char *s` 2. Can't you remove whitespace?

Comment: @Challenger5 Thanks! I used a random online byte counter website yesterday, tried it now on TIO, code is a lot shorter, thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: Suggest `printf("%d %d",s[i]-'x'?:a,s[i=L?L-s:i]-'x'?a:b);` instead of `if(L!=0)i=(int)(L-s);printf("%d %d",s[i]=='x'?a:0,s[i]=='x'?b:a);` and `index()` instead of `strchr()`